# Sqlite wait for database to open

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, callback

I recently started to use javascript and electron. I want to use sqlite as a database technology. My problem is when I call:

```
OpenDB(dbPath);
CreateTable("sampleTable", "Column1 TEXT NOT NULL, Column2 TEXT NOT NULL");
```

Program actually calls CreateTable function without waiting database to open. **If I call these two functions with delay program works as intended.** I wrote function definitions below:

```
export function OpenDB(dbPath) {
    projectDB = new sqlite3.Database(dbPath, (err) => {
    if (err) {
       console.error(err.message)
       this.result =  false;
       return;
    }
    console.log('SQlite project database created.');
  });
}

export function CreateTable(tableName, tableColumns) {
    configDB.run('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + tableName + ' (' + tableColumns + ')' , (err) => {
        if(err) {
            console.error(err);
            console.log("Table couldn't created.")
            return;
        }
        console.log("Table created.")

    })

}
```

So my question is how can I make CreateTable function wait until the database actually opened? 
From what I understand from my readings I need to create callback function but I couldn't manage to do it successfully. And more I read more I confused. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let db;
export function OpenDB(dbPath, cb) {
  db = new sqlite3.Database(dbPath, cb); 
}

export function CreateTable(tableName, tableColumns, cb) {
    db.run('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + tableName + ' (' + tableColumns + ')', cb);
}
```

And welcome to callback hell

```
OpenDb(dpPath, function (err) {
  if (err) 
     return console.error(err.message);

  CreateTable("sampleTable", "Column1 TEXT NOT NULL, Column2 TEXT NOT NULL", function (err) {
    if (err)
        return console.error(err);
  });
})
```

If this way is inappropriate then use [promisification](https://javascript.info/promisify)

```
let db;
export function OpenDB(dbPath) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    db = new sqlite3.Database(dbPath, err => err ? resolve() : reject(err));
  });
}

export function CreateTable(tableName, tableColumns) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    db.run('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + tableName + ' (' + tableColumns + ')', 
       err => err ? resolve() : reject(err));
  }); 
}
```

And usage

```
OpenDb(dbPath)
  .then(() => CreateTable("sampleTable", "Column1 TEXT NOT NULL, Column2 TEXT NOT NULL"))
  .then(() => CreateTable("sampleTable2", "Column1 TEXT NOT NULL, Column2 TEXT NOT NULL"))
  .then(() => console.log('Complete'))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 1):

@Aikon Mogwai's answer is good. My suggestion using async/await:

```
async function createTables() {
    let db = new sqlite3.Database(tbpath);
    await create_table(db, 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sampleTable(Column1 TEXT NOT NULL, Column2 TEXT NOT NULL)')
    await create_table(db, 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sampleTable2(Column1 TEXT NOT NULL, Column2 TEXT NOT NULL)')
    db.close();
    logger.info("Created database.")
}


async function create_table(db: any, query: any) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        db.run(query, function (err: any, rows: any) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("promise rejected")
                return reject(err);
            }
            resolve(rows);
        });
    });
}
```

The `new sqlite3.Database(tbpath)` doesn't have to be awaited. At least I don't have problems with that.